# Negate a condition if a bool is FALSE

Tags: code-golf, tips

Let's say I have a condition expression `x` and that I want to check if it is TRUE or FALSE depending on the value of a boolean `y`:

```
y ? x : !x
```

Is there a way to express it without repeating `x` expression? Something like how we can get a number or its opposite depending on a bool, without repeating the number in the expression:

```
number * (opposite ? -1 : 1)
```

Example, note the repetition of `date.hour < 12` that I want to avoid:

```
tellTheThruth = FALSE; // or TRUE 
if (tellTheThruth && date.hour < 12 || !tellTheThruth && !(date.hour < 12) {
    print "It's AM"
} else {
    print "It's PM" 
}
```

Is it possible in all common languages (I was thinking in Javascript and I can't find a solution)? If not, is there some language in which you can?

Comment: Checking whether the two bools are equal should work: `y==x`, or `tellTheTruth == (date.hour < 12)`. Are you asking though for actual code, where readability is a concern, or for brevity in code golf contests?

Comment: You could always get `1` or `0` for truthy and falsey respectively and then XOR them, is that what you want? example: `tellTheTruth ^ (date.hour < 12)`

Comment: voting to re-open. golfing tips questions are on-topic here.

Comment: @Sparr Still, what in this question tells you that he's trying to *golf something*?

Comment: Like I said in chat, his question explicitly asks about removing repetition of an expression (`x`)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't really look like a code-golfing tips question to me.

Comment: @isaacg I would also, but I can't.

Comment: @xnor Great, seems I and [this guy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160697/is-it-good-practice-to-use-the-xor-operator-in-java-for-boolean-checks) fell into the same trap. How didn't I thought about that yesterday?!? As [someone else one says in that popular question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/160697/is-it-good-practice-to-use-the-xor-operator-in-java-for-boolean-checks#comment50249_160700), I shouldn't code (or make questions about booleans) at midnight... XD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for two booleans x and y, `y ? x : !x` can be rewritten as `y ^ !x` (y XOR NOT x) or similar in most languages.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell

```
import Data.Bool.Extras
bool=<<not
```

`bool` from `Data.Bool.Extras` is similar to the `?` operator in other languages. It takes 3 arguments, a False case, a True case and a boolean to decide which one to use. `=<<` works here in function context ( i.e. `(f=<<g) x` is `f (g x) x`), so we can use it as `(bool=<<not) <x> <y>` which is `bool (not <x>) <x> <y>`.

Example: `(bool=<<not) True False` -> `False`.